# Copy command - deep or shallow copy?

Tags: swift, swift3, copy

When I am copying the object with copy command in iOS (swift / objective c), Will that be a shallow copy or a deep copy ?

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
var copyStr = str.copy()
```

and

```
var originalArray = [1, 2, 3, 4] as NSArray
var copyArray = originalArray.copy()

withUnsafePointer(to: &originalArray) {
    print(" originall address: \($0)")
}

withUnsafePointer(to: &copyArray) {
    print(" copy address: \($0)")
}
```

Help me with the lines above , is this a deep copy or a shallow copy ?

> The issue is , this behaviour in objective c is showing me the same
>   address with both string and array which is shallow copy and in swift3
>   it is showing me different address which is deep copy

Comment: First, `String` is a value type (a `struct`), so if you want to copy it you just do `var copyStr = str`. To include `copy()` in there suggests a misconception about how value types work in Swift. Using `copy()` is more of an Objective-C pattern. Second, shallow or deep copy is generally a concept that we discuss with relation to collections, not simple strings. Third, do you care what's really going on there or just what the resulting behavior is. Notably, collection value types have some interesting copy-on-write behaviors that complicate questions like "what does `let foo = array` do?".

Comment: In Objective-C, when you copy a `NSArray`, it's generally a shallow copy. If you want a deep copy, you generally do [`initWithArray:copyItems:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsarray/1408557-initwitharray?language=objc). The same is true with the [equivalent `NSDictionary` method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdictionary/1410124-init).

Comment: Edited @Rob......

Comment: so , how can a different address give me shallow copy ? it is stating that if there are reference to different address it is deep copy , right?

Comment: The shallow/deep distinction does not refer to the address of the top level object, but rather the objects within the collection. The top level object will be different on `copy`, but the elements of the collection will be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `copy` performs a shallow copy (a copy of the collection, but the objects in the array are not copied). E.g.

```
let obj1 = Object(value: 1)
let obj2 = Object(value: 2)
let obj3 = Object(value: 3)

let originalArray = [obj1, obj2, obj3] as NSArray
let copyArray = originalArray.copy() as! NSArray

print(String(format: "original address: %p", originalArray))

for obj in originalArray {
    print(String(format: "    %p", obj as! Object))
}

print(String(format: "copy address: %p", copyArray))

for obj in copyArray {
    print(String(format: "    %p", obj as! Object))
}
```

Note, I use an object other than `NSNumber` and `NSString`, as those have optimizations that may make looking at addresses misleading.

The member objects of these two arrays point to the same objects (i.e. a shallow copy).

```
original address: 0x618000044920
    0x6180000277e0
    0x618000027f00
    0x618000027ea0
copy address: 0x618000044920
    0x6180000277e0
    0x618000027f00
    0x618000027ea0
```

In fact, as you can see, because it's an immutable `NSArray`, it appears to optimize this where the copy is actually returning the same array instance. If you use mutable arrays, `NSMutableArray`, you'll see two unique arrays returned, as you'd expect, but they will still point to the same collection of objects.

But, if you use `NSArray(array:copyItems:)` with `true` for `copyItems`, you will get two unique arrays with unique copies of each member object:

```
let copyArray = NSArray(array: originalArray as! [Any], copyItems: true)
```

That yields a deep copy (two unique arrays where the individual member objects are copied and they, too, have unique addresses):

```
original address: 0x618000059e60
    0x618000027ae0
    0x618000028340
    0x618000028280
copy address: 0x61800005ba20
    0x618000028800
    0x618000028aa0
    0x618000028400
```

---

See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsarray/1408557-init) for `init(array:copyItems:)` which says:

> The `copy(with:​)` method performs a shallow copy. If you have a collection of arbitrary depth, passing `true` for the `flag` parameter [of `init(array:copyItems:)`] will perform an immutable copy of the first level below the surface. If you pass `false` the mutability of the first level is unaffected. In either case, the mutability of all deeper levels is unaffected.

---

Personally, though, if writing Swift, I'd generally use `Array` and `Dictionary` value types rather than the old `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` types.

Comment: And Just for the knowledge , why don't they have copy for Array and Dictionary ? because in swift they are made from struct ? is that the sole reason ? @Rob

Comment: Yes, they're value types (`struct`) and, as a result, they _always_ copy automatically. See WWDC 2015 [Building Better Apps with Value Types in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/414/).

Answer (score 0):

String in Swift are Value Types. For all Value Types, a new copy of the existing String value is created.

From Apple Document.

> Swift’s copy-by-default String behavior ensures that when a function
>   or method passes you a String value, it is clear that you own that
>   exact String value, regardless of where it came from. You can be
>   confident that the string you are passed will not be modified unless
>   you modify it yourself.

Hope this helps

Comment: But its same with collection type , see the edited question , its giving me deep in swift 3 and shallow in objC

Comment: Since String is valye type it will be always Deep Copy. Obj C NSSting is not value type so by default it will be shallow copy. Same way Collections are reference type so same behavior shallow copy